# How to specify a cluster name for a kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I'm trying to initialize a Kubernetes cluster using Kubeadm.

I basically have 3 questions. 1 big one and 2 "sub questions" if you will

I am having difficulty in assigning a cluster name to the cluster. When I read the `kubeadm` [docs](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/apis/kubeadm/v1beta1), it has a flag `--config` where you can specify the yml file which will be used to initialize the cluster.

There is an example yml file specified on their page but that file has a lot of configurations that I do not know how to set. So therefore I created a config file as below:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: InitConfiguration
advertiseAddress: "10.62.194.4" # is this correct (see below)
bindPort: 6443
---
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterConfiguration
networking:
    podSubnet: "10.62.194.0/16" # is this correct (see below)
controlPlaneEndpoint: "10.62.194.4:6443" #is this correct (see below)
clusterName: "dev-cluster"
```

I initialize like this `sudo kubeadm init --config=config.yml`

However, when I try to initialize the above file, it doesnt work as expected and times out after a while

The error is similar to this:
    Unfortunately, an error has occurred: timed out waiting for the condition
    This error is likely caused by:
        - The kubelet is not running
        - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

When I do a `docker ps` I can see kube-system containers all running, with no exited containers. The containers that are running are
kube-scheduler
kube-controller-manager_kube-controller
kube-apiserver
etcd-ubuntu
kube-controller-manager-ubuntu-xenial

Second question: are cluster names important? I want to set a cluster name because I am planning to set up 3 clusters for 3 different environments, which would mean 3 different contexts. If all 3 have the same default cluster name, will there be an issue?

Also a final third part to this question if the IP of the server ( this is also the master ) I am running the commands is `10.62.194.4` are the fields `advertiseAddress`, `podSubnet` and `controlPlaneEndpoint` correct? I am planning to add one more node to this cluster and the IP of that node is 10.62.194.5
Thanks

Comment: Did solutions below solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you are planing to setup highly available kubernetes setup. You have to configure/provide the Loadbalancer IP on the controlPlaneEndpoint option.

```
  apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta1
  kind: ClusterConfiguration
  networking:
      podSubnet: "10.62.194.0/16" 
  controlPlaneEndpoint: "Loadbalancer IP:6443" 
  clusterName: "dev-cluster"
```

You have to add --upload-certs option on the kubeadm initialization command as below.

```
  sudo kubeadm init --config=config.yaml --upload-certs
```

The output of the above command provides the join command to add another master node on to this HA kubernetes cluster setup.

Comment: Why is it necessary to add `--upload-certs`? I mean I understand what it does, but how is uploading the certs to a secret is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little bit late but it seems the podSubnet is overlapping the subnet you have your nodes. I would use a different /16 subnet for this and assign the nodes (VMs or bare metal machines) to another subnet.